# Learning Road map for floer homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry

Recently I have been interested in floer homology.Currently I am reading Dietmar Salamon's lecture notes.So can you please suggest papers by floer which are sort of must read to learn floer homology?
Also any suggestion on learning roadmap for floer homology is welcome(so far I have read hatcher and Ana Cannas Da Silva's symplectic geometry)

Comment: You should really have a faculty advisor to give you advice on this. "Floer homology" can mean a lot of things. Which notes of Salamon's are you reading? And why do you want to learn Floer homology?

Comment: are you still looking for an answer? If yes, I can you some further references.